# What kind of droppings are these?

Tags: pest-control

Can anyone identify the creature whose droppings (I assume they are droppings) are found on top of this gas water heater?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Why is your cold water insulated?

Comment: @MosheKatz Got me. I'd have to ask the builders what they were thinking, but they're long gone. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely a mouse or rat, possibly a mouse-rat.